# What does the 'ps -o cputime' show in the TIME column?

Tags: macos, command-line, cpu, time

The macOS `ps` gives the TIME like this:

```
UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
    0 50769 80598   0  9:09pm ttys000    0:00.00 egrep 96222|PID
  666 96222 95653   0 10:09pm ttys006    0:00.01 /bin/bash ./count_numbers_octal.sh
  666 96226 96222   0 10:09pm ttys006  224:07.09 od -o
  666 96227 96222   0 10:09pm ttys006  613:25.59 cut -c1
```

The manual page of `ps` explains it like this:

```
The time the command started.  If the command started less than 24
hours ago, the start time is displayed using the “%l:ps.1p” format
described in strftime(3).  If the command started less than 7 days
ago, the start time is displayed using the “%a6.15p” format.
Otherwise, the start time is displayed using the “%e%b%y” format.
```

What exactly does that mean? I've looked at `strftime(3)`, and it isn't clear to me if it is [seconds].[milliseconds] or [seconds].[tenth of seconds] or something else.

Answer (score 1):

I've investigated this, and, the meaning of `TIME` in the macOS (ex BSD) `ps` command is:

`224:07.09`

Which translates to:

224 hours
7   minutes
9   centiseconds